# restart Jquery setInterval and reset all vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, setinterval, clearinterval

i have some radio buttons with class = active

```
  <div id="radioset1">
   <input type="radio" class="active" id="radio1" name="radio" />
   <input type="radio" class="active" id="radio2" name="radio" />
   <input type="radio" class="active" id="radio3" name="radio" />
  </div>
  <div id="counter_up">xy</div>
```

I want to add a timer to the div "counter_up" to show when was the last change of the radiobutton.

therefore i added some jquery code like this:

```
  $('.active').click(function() {

    clearInterval(myInterval);
    var counter = 0;
    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {

      ++counter;
      $('#counter_up').html('Aktiv seit ' + counter + ' Sekunden');

    },1000);

 });
```

my code is working, so when i click one of the radio buttons the first time everything works fine.

the problem is, when i click another radio button, the var counter dont starts with 0.

I tried to use delete var and clearInterval, but it doesnt work. 
can somebody help?

Comment: Javascript variables declared in a function have function scope.  So I'm thinking `myInterval` will be out of scope when you attempt to clear it.  You could try making it a global var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `myInterval` globally and restructure your code a bit to make it counting from `0`:

```
var myInterval = null;
$('.active').click(function() {

    clearInterval(myInterval);
    var counter = 0;
    var timer = function() {
        $('#counter_up').html('Aktiv seit ' + (counter++) + ' Sekunden');
    };
    timer();
    myInterval = setInterval(timer, 1000);

});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/x3Z6C/